# Making two headers directly below each other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to write two headers directly above one another with no space in between like so:

header1
header2

The top of header2 should almost be touching the bottom of header1.

I'm using bootstrap and there is a large gap between the two headers.
I've tried overriding the class to remove the top and bottom margins but the gap is still there.

How can I do this?

```
<div class="row even">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 id="row-bottom-margin" class="text-center"> A Title </h1>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3 id="row-top-margin" class="text-center"> Title 2 </h3>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#row-top-margin{
margin-top: 0px;
}

#row-bottom-margin{
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Where is CSS, where is HTML?

Comment: What CSS are you using to override the class? The CSS will need higher specificity than the CSS bootstrap uses to override it. Look in chrome dev tools to see what the CSS is doing

Comment: Provide your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the margin of the headers and apply negative margin to the `h2`:

```
h1, h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: -0.5em;
}
```

make sure your css is applied after the bootstrap css, so that the styles get overwritten.

example: http://www.bootply.com/0Njb4PrXSi

---

**edit:** updated example for your code (http://www.bootply.com/3HG9MmaROJ)

rearrange the html like:

```
<div class="row even">
    <div class="no-margin col-md-12">
        <h1 class="text-center">A Title</h1>
        <h3 class="text-center">Title 2</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

and use `no-margin` class to change the margin:

```
.no-margin h1, .no-margin h3 {
    margin 0;
}

.no-margin h3 {
    margin: -0.75em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with giving -ve margin.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#row-top-margin{
margin-top: 0px;
}

#row-bottom-margin{
margin-bottom: -10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row even">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 id="row-bottom-margin" class="text-center"> A Title </h1>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3 id="row-top-margin" class="text-center"> Title 2 </h3>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```